# How to convert Yaml to csv and vice versa

Tags: php, csv, yaml

I have an application and I want to make the translation.

I want to externalise the translation and people who translate my application wants an Excel spreedsheet.

I have my messages in yaml format but I don't know how to extract them and make a csv or a spreedsheet.

The second step is that I want to extract the csv file to make a yaml file.

I have you got an idea?

Help please

Comment: FYI, Yaml is not tied to Symfony2. To your question, yes it's possible. have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to convert the YAML files containing translations. This files are basically key values stored like this:

```
button.ok.value: Ok
button.ok.tooltip: Commits the action
```

Of course YAML can be more complicated, but if you have something like this, just replace the ':' char with ',' then save the file as CSV (or change the extension), open it using Excel. Then you can save it as xls format or whatever format you want.

If your file uses hierarchical nodes like:

```
button:
    ok:
        value: Ok
        tooltip: Commits the action
```

Then you might want to write some script to iterate over the values (that's a tree traversal) and write the values to a file.

You should provide an example of how your YAML looks like since it's a very flexible format.

Comment: M'y files has hierarchical nodes as your second examples

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv = "out.csv";
$yaml = "in.yml";

fputcsv($csv, yaml_parse_file($yaml));
```

Requires http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml